# Passing uint8_t to atomic_clr

Tags: c, atomic

I get a compiler error when passing a `uint8_t` to `atomic_clr`. The error is: `"passing argument 1 from incompatible pointer type"`.

Why is that?

Comment: Can you show us a little piece of your code?

Comment: I disagree it is off-topic.  Under explained, but that's par for the course around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be pointer to volatile unsigned

```
#include <atomic.h>

void atomic_clr( volatile unsigned * loc,
                 unsigned bits );
```

Comment: Ok, so it should be at least 32 bits? Why is that? I was wondering about this.

Comment: well, if it was only 8 bits, not many bits to fiddle.... consider accepting answer.